# loop over directories to echo its content

Tags: bash

The directories are variables set to the full-path

```
for e in "$DIR_0" "$DIR_1" "$DIR_2"
do
    for i in $e/*
    do
        echo $i
    done
```

The output for each line is the full path. I want only the name of each file

Comment: Ok, i will have a look at basename. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `basename`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Bash equivalent of `basename`:

```
echo "${i##*/}"
```

It strips off everything before and including the last slash.

Comment: At the moment i prefer this solution, as it seems like the most easy one.
I got enough to think about. Thanks for all the posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly do not wish to recurse you can achieve that more succinctly with this find command:

```
find "$DIR_0" "$DIR_1" "$DIR_2" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec basename{} \;
```

If you wish to recurse over subdirs simply leave out maxdepth:

```
find "$DIR_0" "$DIR_1" "$DIR_2" -type f  -exec basename{} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

to traveling a directory recursively with bash

try this you can find it [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Batch_File)

```
#! /bin/bash


    indent_print()
    {
        for((i=0; i < $1; i++)); do
        echo -ne "\t"
        done
        echo "$2"
    }

    walk_tree()
    {
        local oldifs bn lev pr pmat
        if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]; then
        if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
            pmat=".*"
        else
            pmat="$2"
        fi
        walk_tree "$1" "$pmat" 0
        return
        fi
        lev=$3
        [ -d "$1" ] || return
        oldifs=$IFS
        IFS=""
        for el in $1/ *; do
        bn=$(basename "$el")
        if [[ -d "$el" ]]; then
            indent_print $lev "$bn/"
            pr=$( walk_tree "$el" "$2" $(( lev + 1)) )
            echo "$pr"
        else
            if [[ "$bn" =~ $2 ]]; then
            indent_print $lev "$bn"
            fi
        fi
        done
        IFS=$oldifs
    }

    walk_tree "$1" "\.sh$"
```

Comment: It never finishes. It gets stuck in the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

See also the POSIX compliant Bash functions to replace basename & dirname here:

http://cfaj.freeshell.org/src/scripts/